# What's the meaning of a '#' character before owner?

Tags: users, ls

What does the `#` character preceding the owner name mean?

For example:

```
me@server /dir/sub/sub-sub $ ll v* x*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 #owner   group          1176 Jun 25  2009 vfc.sh
-rw-r-----   1 #owner   group             6 Jun 22  2011 xx
-rwxrwxrwx   1 #owner   group           107 May 25  2010 xx.sh
-rw-r-----   1 #owner   group         10139 Jan  7  2013 xxx
```

Comment: The username starts with `#`

Comment: Possibly someone thought they could comment out a user in `/etc/passwd` by putting a `#` in front of the username, but this just causes the username to change; any files owned by that user will now show as `#username` instead.

Comment: @jimmij: Or better yet, just show the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: Try `getpw '#owner'`, and compare to `getpw $USER`

Comment: @KeithThompson Or, in this case, just `stat xx` (or another of the files).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Sure, but seeing the actual `/etc/passwd` (or equivalent) entry is likely to get the point across more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that's actually the username. Try checking the passwd file, and you might find that somebody tried to comment out a line:

```
grep owner /etc/passwd
```

If you find that there is a line starting with `#`, then if there is another line which doesn't have it, you may want to remove the line with the `#`. Otherwise, you may just want to remove the `#`. That is, assuming that you don't actually want a user named `#owner`.

In most scripts, a `#` at the start of a line is considered to be a comment. That's not the case in `/etc/passwd`, and so, it is most likely to think that somebody meant to make a line a comment, which, if that worked, would act the same as removing it.

Comment: or `grep ^#owner /etc/passwd` or `getent passwd \#owner`

Comment: Yes, that would be great to be specific. I was hoping, though, that he would see both the "commented" line, and the actual line. I think odds are good that somebody did that before making a copy, but just a guess.

Comment: What Unix variant doesn't support `#` to comment out lines in `/etc/passwd`? AFAIR at least Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, OSF/1 and SunOS do.